# batch expansion variable cannot be used in substring replace function

Tags: string, variables, batch-file, replace, expansion

im beginner, my task is something to do with renaming files in folder, first of all here is a piece of my code:-

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set tempLogDate=0
set g=0

for /r %targetStore% %%i IN (*2013*.*) do (
  set tempLogDate=9
  set g=!g:%tempLogDate%=!
)
```

the problem is variable %tempLogDate% value is 0 instead of 9, i know i need to use variable expansion(which i have) but i cant replace code "set g=!g:*%tempLogDate%.rar=!" to "set g=!g:*!tempLogDate!.rar=!", i try escape character but no result, guys pls help me..thanks in advance

Comment: before that, here is original code of string replacement that i refer to 
@echo off
set string=This is my string to work with.
set string=%string:to work with.=%
echo %string%

Output = This is my string

base on it, i need to initialize value "to work with." into string variable since i need to use it in loop, so thats the mess,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look for `delayed expansion`, `setlocal /?` and `endlocal /?`. Example:

```
@ECHO OFF &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "tempLogDate=0"
set "g=0"

for /r %targetStore% %%i IN (*2013*.*) do (
  set "tempLogDate=9"
  CALL SET "g=%%g:!tempLogDate!=%%"
)
```

Comment: wah you are batch GODLIKE, this is second time u solved my problem with very specific answer, many thanks, ~god bless u @Endoro~